# odoo 13 how to add one2many with import functionality to custom module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

Hi and new to odoo development since I was using the interface all the time.

I wanted to create a custom module that the user can create a record then add some information in an "order line format"  but if the record existed he would be able to import that would add a new lines "order line"

so my question is first is it possible to import to `line`

if so how to create a line

I tried reading the docs but could not figure it out

EDIT:
order line functionality is one2many fields

Comment: Do you want to use an existing line in order line field?

Comment: No, I want to create a new one but is it possible to import data into a one2many
form an excel file

Answer (score 0):

You must use the external ID of the record to which you want to import rows.

The following example imports a new bank line in `banks` field of the partner specified by the external id (*Azure Interior* in the demo database):

```
"id","bank_ids/acc_number"
"base.res_partner_12","GB87BARC20658244971655"
```

***Edit:***

You need to specify the required fields.`acc_number` is required in `res.partner.bank` and `bank_ids` is the name of the One2many field in `res.partner`. You can try to export an existing order to get an idea of the field names to use.

For orders, there are SQL constraints that will prevent you from creating rows if certain fields are not set.

***Purchase order example:***

```
"id","order_line/product_id/id","order_line/name","order_line/product_qty","order_line/product_uom/id","order_line/price_unit","order_line/date_planned"
"purchase.purchase_order_4","point_of_sale.whiteboard_pen","point_of_sale.whiteboard_pen","3","uom.product_uom_unit","158","2020-05-17 10:48:35"
```

****Sale order example****:

```
"id","order_line/product_id/id","order_line/name","order_line/product_uom_qty","order_line/product_uom/id","order_line/price_unit"
"sale.sale_order_3","point_of_sale.whiteboard_pen","point_of_sale.whiteboard_pen","3","uom.product_uom_unit","158"
```

Comment: can you plz add more details I don't even know how to create the one2many like the one in order line

Comment: I added examples for sale and purchase orders. Check my edit

Comment: Did you figure out how to import the file?